# Prevent install code/script during cpack package generation

Tags: cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have to use the `CMake` `INSTALL(CODE` and `INSTALL(SCRIPT` signatures with some custom code installing some additional files which can only be generated at install time. These files should however not end up in packages generated by `CPack`. Especially I wouldn't even know how to do that as the magic packaging directory is not available inside `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

How can I disable execution of `CODE` and `SCRIPT` install targets during `cpack` packaging?

Answer (score 0):

Source :[CMake Install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html)

> The SCRIPT and CODE signature:
>
> install([[SCRIPT < file >] [CODE < code >]] [...])
>
> The SCRIPT form will invoke the given CMake script files during
>   installation. If the script file name is a relative path it will be
>   interpreted with respect to the current source directory. The CODE
>   form will invoke the given CMake code during installation. Code is
>   specified as a single argument inside a double-quoted string. For
>   example, the code
>
> install(CODE "MESSAGE(\"Sample install message.\")")
>
> will print a message during installation.

The process of CPack is `make > make install > execute install scripts > pack all files to bundle`

Note: These scripts are not the package bundle scripts. [CMake Generators](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cpack/PackageGenerators) shows how to add package bundle scripts.

I think [CMake Generators](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cpack/PackageGenerators) is what you need.